# multistep registration from in drupal 7 need to add a user and role

Tags: users

Here is my method

```
test_two_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $page_one_values = $form_state['page_values'][1];
  drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted'));
  $page_one_values = $form_state['page_values'][1];
  drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted. name="@username @email", password=@password', array('@username' => $page_one_values['username'], '@email' => $page_one_values['email'], '@password' => $page_one_values['password'])));
}
```

What i am trying to do is to add a user to my multi-step form.

I guess my two questions are how to add a user and also assign that particular user to a role.

Would it be possible for someone to give a short example.

Comment: hi Clive thank you for sorting out the code markup but would it be possible to shed some light on creating a user object for my custom registration form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   // Register this new user.
    $roles = user_roles();
    $userinfo = array(
      'name' => $name,
      'pass' => user_password(),
      'init' => $name,
      'status' => 1,
      'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
      // This is where we are different from the default function.
      'roles'        => array(array_search('campus_student', $roles) => 1),
      // the field_* values come from custom columns added through
      // thhe admin ui under manage fields for users.
      'field_first_name'   => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array( 0 => array('value' => $get_ldap_details['first_name']))),
      'field_last_name'    => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array( 0 => array('value' => $get_ldap_details['last_name']))),
      'field_perm_number'  => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array( 0 => array('value' => $get_ldap_details['campus_perm_number']))),
      'mail' => $get_ldap_details['mail'],
    );
    $account = user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $userinfo);
```

**EDIT:** You can see how drupal itself typically creates in a user via [drupal_external_login_register()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_external_login_register/7). The above example uses some API calls to get all Roles and assigns very clearly X additional roles, it also sets up additional drupal Fields tied to the user entity.